Is it possible to make a step-by-step build using cargo?
I have a multi-workspace cargo project:
cli/
server/
test/
Cargo.toml

In parent Cargo.toml
[workspace]
members = [
    "server",
    "cli",
    "tests",
]
resolver = "1"

In test workspace a have a bunch of integration tests which are depends on build of cli crate. So, I just want to run cargo test to run all my tests that are depends on builded cli executable file. But now it's fails with:
test tests::should_output_help ... FAILED

failures:

---- tests::should_output_help stdout ----
Error: Cause: Cargo command not found: /Users/l3r8y/code/fakehub/target/debug/cli

But if i'll run cargo build before tests everything would be fine. So question is – Is it possible to make cargo test build cli create and run tests only after cli has been built?

Does this answer your question? How do you run the main binary and then run tests based on it in Rust?

Cargo has special support for the tests of a specific package accessing binaries from that package. It does not yet have anything for using binaries from a separate package (that would be artifact dependencies, which are not implemented yet). Therefore:

Move your relevant tests from the test/ package to cli/tests/ (the integration test location for the cli package).
In your tests, use env!("CARGO_BIN_EXE_cli") as the path to the command to execute. This environment variable is automatically set, when a test is being compiled or run, with the path to each binary in the same package. (Docs)

